# What's the correct way to solve the CORS issue in Spring Boot where hundreds of partners should be allowed to connect to the API?

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I'm a junior dev and the company I work at has a few hundreds partners and each of them have their own website. They would like to integrate an API from my company and thus making calls to our API. I guess that would trigger the CORS issue, and while I know how to do that for a reasonable amount of origins, what's the best practice for hundreds of origins?
How do I whitelist these partners to connect to our API? I guess allowing all connections would not be safe(?).
I use Spring Boot for backend, and Angular-TypeScript for frontend with NX.

And should the CORS be handled in the frontend as a fastfail mechanism or in the backend? The goal is to have a monorepo and the architecture includes BFF.

Any experience will be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Why is the number of allowed origins worrying you? Performance? Also, how is the API authenticated? Via cookies or some other means?

Comment: @CrossOrigin on your controllers.

Comment: _should the CORS be handled in the frontend as a fastfail mechanism or in the backend?_ CORS is always configured on the server side, and instructs browsers to relax some of their default restrictions. There's nothing you need to do on the client side.

Comment: @jub0bs security mostly. People will be able to go on our partners' websites and book appointments - but the functionality is our company's API which is integrated into our partners' websites.

Comment: @Antoniossss won't that allow everyone to connect to our API? Is that a good practice?

Comment: @Harvey So your question is more about how to manage this large number of allowed origins than about CORS itself, right?

Comment: @Harvey Is your API not authenticated?

Comment: @jub0bs yes that is correct, what is the best way to manage the whitelisting. The API is not authenticated. The users are basically people who would like to book an appointment, no credentials or authentication are used. Should it? If so, what would be the solution? A JWT token using Spring Security? Sorry if my terminology is not accurate, I'm kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: CORS is no substitute for server-side authorisation. Any user agent other than a browser (e.g. curl) will be able to interact with your API, if it has no auth in place. Do you realise that?

Comment: @Harvey everyone is allowed to access your API right now anyway - its just a matter of not calling your API directly with AJAX but with own backend.